# Block Element Not Responsive

Tags: css, mobile

I have five square buttons in a row that I am displaying as a lock. However when viewing on a mobile phone the 5 icons do not stack, they bunch up and overlap with the element below them. I thought that adding the clear element would resolve that but it doesn't. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks so much, I greatly appreciate it!

```
.menu {
    height: 100px;
    clear: both;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    margin-top:35px;
}

.icons {
    height: 100px;
    width:100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

[image: This is what I am seeing on mobile]

Comment: Question is not clear...Can you give html code or jsfiddle?

Comment: as a point `clear:both;` will force the `.menu` to clear anything to the side of the element! could you provide a example of you working code above in a fiddle or similar?

Comment: `clear` only applies to  items that have been `floated` ...yours have not.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, here is the fiddle of the menu... https://jsfiddle.net/f8b8181v/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `height` property from your `.menu` class (or,  at the very least, changing it to `min-height`) will allow your parent element's height to expand to fit its contents, thereby pushing the content that follows it down the page.

See examples below for an illustration.

```css
div{
  background:green;
  margin:5px 0;
  padding:5px;
}
p{
  font-family:sans-serif;
  margin:0;
}
div p{
  background:red;
  min-height:40px;
}
div~div{
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This paragraph's parent doesn't have set height and therefore will expand to fit the height of this paragraph</p>
</div>
<p>This is just a placeholder</p>
<div>
  <p>This paragraph's parent has a set height and therefore won't expand to fit the height of this paragraph</p>
</div>
<p>This is just a placeholder</p>
```